# Rails - Sending image using Faraday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, directory, faraday

I'm trying to make a request to an API sending an image and some other data, and getting the response. That's my code:

```
file = "assets/images/test.jpg"
conn = Faraday.new(:url => "api_url" ) do |faraday|
  faraday.request :multipart
end
payload = { :profile_pic => Faraday::UploadIO.new(file, 'image/jpeg') }
conn.post "/test", payload
```

My first problem is that I'm always getting the following error:

```
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - assets/images/test.png)
```

I've tried all the paths I could imagine. Where should be saved the image in directories to be found by Faraday?

The second question is about the response, how can I get the response and handle it?

The third one is that, I haven't understand what's the utility of the first parameter of the last call:

```
conn.post "/hello", payload
```

I've written "/hello" but don't have any idea about what's the real usage.

And the last one. Could I send a raw image saved in a variable instead of sending a path to Faraday?

**EDIT**

Now it's working, this is the solution:
Be aware that url must be only until `.com`, the rest of the path must go on `conn.post` like this example `/v1/search`.
`c.adapter :net_http` was needed too.
Message response is correctly handled in json variable.

Solution:

```
  url = 'http://url.com'

  file = Rails.root.to_s + "/app/assets/images/test.jpg"
  conn = Faraday.new(:url => url ) do |c|
    c.request :multipart
    c.adapter :net_http
  end
  payload = { :image => Faraday::UploadIO.new(file, 'image/jpeg'), :token => token}

  response = conn.post '/v1/search', payload
  json = JSON.parse response.body
```

Comment: what should i do if i  just want to send audio with an http request with specifying image.jpeg @user15

Answer (score 1):

You should try this for your first question :

```
file = Rails.root.to_s + "/app/assets/images/test.jpg"
```

For your third question, the first parameters allows you to construct the right URL from the base "api_url". Please see the example from the [Readme](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/3e6654667f6c6922eae296da090c5f1dc52f2abf/README.md).

```
## POST ##

conn.post '/nigiri', { :name => 'Maguro' }  # POST "name=maguro" to http://sushi.com/nigiri
```

Comment: In fact the correct answer is `file = Rails.root.to_s + "/app/assets/images/test.jpg"`
But it have helped me to find it out.
And about the other points? any idea?

Comment: @user1573607 I updated my answer. (I don't know the anwser for the second question, Perhaps you should print payload[:profile_pic] after the `conn.post` call and see what you get?)